# How to read font size and font name in .docx in Apache POI(java)

Tags: java, fonts, apache-poi, document, docx

Here is my code.

```
XWPFRun run = runlist.get(0);
double fontsize = (double)(run.getFontSize());
String fontfamily = (String)run.getFontFamily();
```

When it read the .docx file it will sometimes return -1 in font size and null in font family.

I know that it's because they are default value but I don't want -1 and null I just want the name of that default value.

How can I read it?

Answer (score 0):

The font/character properties on a [XWPFRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html) only return the override details, so settings which are different on that run to the surrounding text

If the run is using the default stylings, you'll need to move up to the [XWPFParagraph](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html) it belongs to (or table etc), then call [getStyleId()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#getStyleID%28%29) to get the style which applies to the paragraph.

Then, on the document, call [XWPFDocument.getStyles()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getStyles%28%2).[getStyle(styleId)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFStyles.html#getStyle%28java.lang.String%29) to get the [XWPFStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFStyle.html) object that applies to the paragraph of interest.

From the style, you can fetch the properties defined in that style such as the font. You may also need to fetch the parent, if the style inherits from one.

Currently, the XWPFStyle object is a bit low level, so patches to improve it would be [gratefully received!](http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html)

Comment: Now I can get the style but I still can't see that XWPFStyle object can call method to fetch those font name and font size. It only has methods to deal with style of the paragraph like Body A Heading1 Heading2 etc.

Comment: You'll need to work with the low-level `CTStyle` object. Well, work with the `CTStyle` briefly, then submit a patch to expose useful stuff on the `XWPFStyle` to avoid future users having to!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I got it fixed with `document.getStyles().getDefaultRunStyle().getFontSize();`

Comment: It is giving some time font size and some time -1 as font size. Could you please post your full code here just to have intuition? I am newbie to POI.

Comment: @OmPrakash the reason of this problem is that your file has already been a doc/docx which has been converted to docx/doc. If you open a blank file and write the same text, with exactly the same format (not copying), you can get the correct font size.